# Laravel Route Redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on a project in Laravel. I have done the login and register page. But when I type in the URL, it doesn't redirect me properly.

When I type **http://localhost:8000/auth/register** or **/login** it just redirects me to the **localhost::8000**.

I think my code in routes.php is ok:

```
//Authentication Routes

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

//Registration Routes

Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Comment: i have olso made the folder "auth" at viwes

Comment: Show us your AuthController please

Comment: I think you might be logged in already... try logging out. first